# Chronoforms Multiplier Data Not Posting to Email

Tags: chronoforms

Chronoforms V.5
Joomla 3.4.3

I'm using the Chronoforms [Multiplier feature](https://www.chronoengine.com/faqs/70-cfv5/5245-how-can-i-use-the-multiplier-in-cfv5.html) to create the example posted on that page. Everything works with the exception of the data from Multiplier not posting to the email. The arrays exists, but the data is not posting in the email template. No error messages are displaying. I was trying to use a PHP loop, but that didn't seem to be working.

PHP LOOP:

```
<?php
if(!empty($form->data["counter"])){
for($i = 0; $i = $form->data["counter"]; $i++){
echo "{shirts_".$i."}";
}
}
?>
```

ARRAY:

```
Array
(
    [option] => com_chronoforms5
    [chronoform] => shirts
    [event] => submit
    [Itemid] => 
    [shirts] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [style] => Standard
                    [size] => L
                    [color] => Red
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [style] => Standard
                    [size] => L
                    [color] => Red
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [style] => Standard
                    [size] => L
                    [color] => Red
                )

        )
```

EMAIL TEMPLATE:

```
<table>
<tr><td>Style</td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>Size</td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>Color</td><td></td></tr>
</table>
```

Anyone familiar with how this can be fixed?

Thank you.

Comment: It might help to share screen captures of the form actions under the "Setup" tab and more of the Email action properties.